# Continuous continuous interaction term in R

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, interaction, model

My problem is visualising a regression I have made, but I am unsure on how to visualise it.

I have an interaction term both variables are continuous. What graphs can I use to accurately depict this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

The basic option, as in the `effects` package is to plot fitted values against one of the interacting regressors while fixing the other regressor at a representative value (say, mean, median or any "interesting" value). For `effects` package syntax and examples, see  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/plot_interactions.html

Alternatively, you may want to calculate the average partial effects (APE), or produce a 3D plot with both interacting regressors at the base. This may be produced using the `margins` package in R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/TechnicalDetails.pdf